# How to use inner join in Django query set

Tags: join, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models in model.py

```
    class Jobs(models.Model):
     JobNumber=models.CharField()
    CustomerName = models.CharField()

class JobTime(models.Model):
    JobNumber = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    WorkHrs = models.FloatField()
    LabourCost = models.FloatField()

class JobMaterial(models.Model):
    JobNumber = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    MaterialCost = models.FloatField()
```

I want to generate a queryset with JobNumber,CustomerName, LabourCost, MaterialCost for all the JobNumbers in Jobs model. Please help, I use Django Version:    3.0.6 and Python Version:   3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think your models should be modified so the foreign keys reside inside the Jobs class. A job should have a JobTime, and a JobMaterial, rather than the other way around. Then, you could do something like:

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    JobNumber=models.CharField()
    CustomerName = models.CharField()
    job_time = models.ForeignKey(JobTime, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    job_material = models.ForeignKey(JobMaterial, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

Jobs.objects.all().select_related('job_time', 'job_material')
```

If you wanted `job_material` to be a one-to-many field on Jobs, then you would use `prefetch_related` instead of `select_related`.

Hope that helps, happy coding!